# Why does the MPMoviePlayerController call MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification, when enter in fullsceen mode

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.5

I want to display a **MPMoviePlayerViewController** in full screen mode, but when the fullscreen button of the movieplayercontroller view is beeing pressed, first the **MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification** gets called, as expacted, but than the **MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification** is also beeing sent. As a reason it says **MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded** and i don't know, what i'm doing wrong. (In addition, i use *iOS 6.0* and *XCode 4.5.1*)

My expactations are, that only the **MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification** is beeing called.

Short explanation to the code below:
The MovieplayerViewController's view is beeing displayed in a tiny subview in my content view. When tapping the fullscreen-button, it first gets displayed as fullscreen but than also calls the exit button and stops playing (no crashes, nothing else).

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

   [playerViewController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

   [playerViewController.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];

   CGRect rect = videoView.frame;

   rect.origin = CGPointZero;

   [playerViewController.view setFrame:rect];

   [playerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];


        //movie this is my contents subview, where i add the viewcontroller's view as a subbview
    [self.videoView addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    [self.videoView setHidden:NO];


    playerViewController.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

    [playerViewController.moviePlayer play];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidFinishNotification:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:playerViewController.moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
                                               object:playerViewController.moviePlayer];    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:playerViewController.moviePlayer];

        //i store the movieplayer in a property, so i can use it for further operations
    self.myPlayer = playerViewController;

    [playerViewController release];
```

And thats it!

When the resize (or fullscreen) button is being pressed, the moviePlayerDidFinishNotification: method also is being called

```
- (void)moviePlayerDidFinishNotification:(NSNotification*) aNotification {

    int reason = [[[aNotification userInfo] valueForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];

    if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded) {

        //movie finished playin

//in debug mode, it stops right at the NSLog

        NSLog(@"");
    }

    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited) {

        //user hit the done button

    }

    else if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError) {

        //error

    }

.. }
```

Is there something i do wrong or is there probably a change since iOS 6.0?

Comment: i have the same problem as you described. i'm using ios 6.1 and xcode 4.6. i think its a MPMoviePlayerViewController bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems to be that there are some problems in the MPMoviePlayerViewController. What helped is to simply us the MPMoviePlayerController only.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference the reason that your player showed in a small window was because you were setting:

```
 [playerViewController.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

   [playerViewController.moviePlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeFill];

   CGRect rect = videoView.frame;

   rect.origin = CGPointZero;

   [playerViewController.view setFrame:rect];

   [playerViewController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];


        //movie this is my contents subview, where i add the viewcontroller's view as a subbview
    [self.videoView addSubview:playerViewController.view];

    [self.videoView setHidden:NO];
```

When you use an MPMoviePlayerViewController it creates it's own view controller. These calls are not necessary and will only create bizarre behavior. That's why the MPMoviePlayerController worked properly because it's designed to work inside another view controller.